# Linux, Fans and PWM

Tags: overheating, fan, fancontrol, lm-sensors

I'm trying to control my fans under Linux. I have 5 chassis fans + CPU fan.
Tried many solutions nothing work.

My MOBO is an Asus Z170 Deluxe, all my fans are 3 pins so no pwm.
Tried to run this commands:

`sudo sensors-detect`

I answered yes to all then :

```
 Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

Driver `lm92':
  * Bus `SMBus I801 adapter at f000'
    Busdriver `i2c_i801', I2C address 0x48
    Chip `lm92' (confidence: 6)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
lm92
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)yes
Successful!

Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are
loaded. You may want to run '/etc/init.d/kmod start'
to load them.

Unloading cpuid... OK
```

Then edited this line in the grub file :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_enforce_resources=lax"
```

Then rebooted and :

```
~$ /etc/init.d/kmod start
[ ok ] Starting kmod (via systemctl): kmod.service


~$ sensors
asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:        0 RPM

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +30.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +27.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +28.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +27.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +27.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

lm92-i2c-0-48
Adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at f000
temp1:        +14.0°C  (low  = +14.0°C, hyst = +28.0°C)
                       (high = +14.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)
                       (crit = +14.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)
```

And

```
$ sudo pwmconfig
************* 
# pwmconfig revision 6243 (2014-03-20)
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

$ fancontrol
Loading configuration from /etc/fancontrol ...
Error: Can't read configuration file
```

I also tried to check thermal zone and found this :

```
$ cd /sys/class/thermal ; ls
cooling_device0  cooling_device2  cooling_device4  cooling_device6  cooling_device8
cooling_device1  cooling_device3  cooling_device5  cooling_device7  thermal_zone0
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/type
x86_pkg_temp
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device0/type
Processor
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device1/type
Processor
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device2/type
Processor
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device3/type
Processor
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device4/type
Processor
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device5/type
Processor
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device6/type
Processor
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device7/type
Processor
$ cat /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device8/type
intel_powerclamp
```

And now I'm out of solutions, any help ?

Answer (score 1):

As explained here [Dell Vostro 200 fan speeds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097474/dell-vostro-200-fan-speeds) - you can try this utility https://github.com/ichiriac/ubuntu-smart-fan, it's based on `lm-sensors` and it will manage the fan speed.

At start you can run it as a monitor in order to seed the fan behavior, and set parameters according to you CPU & FAN behavior.

After calibrating the temperature and thresholds you will be able to run it as a daemon