# Dell Vostro 200 fan speeds

Tags: dell, fancontrol, lm-sensors

I recently installed Ubuntu (18.04.1 LTS) on my old desktop to use as a server. I have been trying to manage the fan speeds, but I cannot get it to work.
I started out with this tutorial:
[How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

After that didn't work I read up that dell's need some more work and tried this:
[Fan speed in ubuntu: pwmconfig no pwm-capable sensor modules installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281478/fan-speed-in-ubuntu-pwmconfig-no-pwm-capable-sensor-modules-installed)

But pwmconfig still says *There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed*.

And i8kctl just gives me this: *1.0 1.0 BJ17YG1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1*

I'm not even sure if i8k is for dell desktops, maybe only for laptops.
If someone can help me out, that would be awesome, Thanks!

Comment: What was the output from sensors-detect?

Comment: @rtaft - coretemp & it87
And I added i8k

Comment: do you know the model of your motherboard?

Comment: Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 10 bytes
Base Board Information
        Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
        Product Name: 0CU409
        Version: ...
        Serial Number: ..****.
        Asset Tag:
        Features:
                Board is a hosting board

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of the articles you posted mentioned modifying grub, so I assume you have not done that.

You don't need i8k.

Focus on it87 in your searches.  One of the common changes is to edit `/etc/default/grub` and append `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` at the end of the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. This thread confirms that it87 needs that grub change: [lm sensors not returning CPU temp (it87)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748615/lm-sensors-not-returning-cpu-temp-it87)

Comment: I didn't link this, but I've tried it before. I'll try it again, maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: Thanks so much! This was the issue. I must of typed it wrong the first time I tried

Answer (score 0):

I've got exactly the same problem with pwmconfig and decided to implement it on my own.

Try this utility https://github.com/ichiriac/ubuntu-smart-fan, it's based on `lm-sensors` and it will manage the fan speed and log them.

At start you can run it as a monitor in order to seed the fan behavior.

After calibrating the temperature and thresholds you will be able to run it as a daemon on your server, and retrieve a log with fan events

Comment: Thanks for this.
I tried it but I get:
Looking for sensors
Unable to find any fan device
Try to run sensors-detect

Comment: Did you ran `sudo sensors-detect` without any error.  If so that means no sensors was detected. Take a look at the /sys/class/hwmon folder, you should find into a subfolder a file named fan[1...x]_label. If you want me to help you could also fill an issue on github, maybe my script does not recognize the configuration

Comment: yes, it runs fine and I get 
coretemp &
it87